# Stubbing web services to test clients using JUnit

Tags: java, web-services, junit, jax-ws

I have some JAX-WS-based web service clients and I'd like to write some JUnit test cases for them.

In my mind, this means stubbing the endpoints.  I want this all to be embedded in my test code, not using a third-party stub application like [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).  Some things I've heard of that might work are:

- [WSUnit](http://java.net/projects/wsunit/) -- However, it seems like it's no longer an active project (notice the broken link)
- [Embedding Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) and expose a static resource web server to respond to the web service requests

**What's the *easiest* way to do this?**

UPDATE: I ended up using Jetty embedded and writing my own handler because I couldn't quickly figure out how to serve POST requests and set the content-type using Jetty's `ResourceHandler`.  It was a quick and easy solution, but if there's something even better it would be good to know.